# How to make a background image full height and centred relative

Tags: html, css

I have a background image with some text on top.

[image: background-image with text]

As you can see the image is cut off at around 70px. I can change the height of the section or main to be 700px and display the full background image, but then the background doesn't become responsive to the page-width.

I want the full height of the background-image to be display, like this:
[image: Ideal Background Size]

But then I also want the image to always be centered to the screen, therefore, responsive!

Does anyone have any suggestions what I should try?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 55px;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1200/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}


/* parliament */

.img3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Hungarian Services at your fingertips</h1>
    <h2>
      Online lessons for kids and adults. Verbal and written training, best tailored to your needs. Translation services. All from a native speaker
    </h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Centered isn't responsive. Do you mean you want the background image to be the heigh tof the viewport and cropped for width? Why aren't you putting the background on the body element?

Comment: I want the centre of the image to be at the centre of the screen regardless of the page width (responsive). The image isn't in the body because there's other stuff in the body, that isn't displayed in this code, I will have 2 pictures after each other and if they are both in the body as background image, they will overlap, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `height: 100vh` to section class. That should resolve the issue.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 55px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1200/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}


/* parliament */

.img3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Hungarian Services at your fingertips</h1>
    <h2>
      Online lessons for kids and adults. Verbal and written training, best tailored to your needs. Translation services. All from a native speaker
    </h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Adding vh, or vw is definitely the solution! Although for me ~30 vw seemed better fit.

Comment: @DeclanDavies, you seem to be trying to get your section to be the same shape as the image. This is a fragile strategy and is in no way responsive. Your requirements are contradictory and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just need [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) set. (Text alignment doesn't affect background.)

Protip: Use intuitive names for your style classes. `img3` doesn't tell readers of your markup anything about what it does. Instead, use something like `.full-height` and `.full-width` to apply those styles (individually), and to make your CSS reusable.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 55px;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1200/800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/* parliament */

.img3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Hungarian Services at your fingertips</h1>
    <h2>
      Online lessons for kids and adults. Verbal and written training, best tailored to your needs. Translation services. All from a native speaker
    </h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of background position property, this is useful knowledge however it cut off the sides of the background image when the width is decreased.

Comment: What do you expect? Do you want the image to distort?

Comment: With adding vh or vw to the height property it doesn't have this problem

Comment: That makes no sense. No image is the same aspect ratio as every screen. There's something about your scenario you haven't explained very well.